# Geometry Nodes: How to calculate Custom normal deformation from real Normals?

Tags: geometry-nodes, mathematics, vector

AFAIK There is no Custom Normals at moment in GN.
As a workaround, Custom Normals can be baked into Vertex colors.
Which works great... until the mesh gets deformed.

Is it possible to calculate in Geometry Nodes the deformed Custom Normals having: Original/Deformed Normals and original Custom Normals?
Is there any other way?

Comment: I found how to calculate face tangent, but this probably would rather need a vertex to face vector...